# Make html listen to java button click

Tags: javascript, java, html, processing, p5.js

I used the Processing IDE to create an app that allows a user to draw on an HTML sketch.

Now, the app looks like this:

[image: sketch]

So when I clicked "new Sketch", it will create a new `sketch.html` file in the folder. Now, I want to create a pie chart by clicking "pie" button, which looks like this:

[image: pie chart]

So basically, my question is how to make html listen to my java customized button function? (Maybe by jsp, but I am not sure)

The button class looks like:

```
public class Button {
  String label; // button label
  float x;      // top left corner x position
  float y;      // top left corner y position
  float w;      // width of button
  float h;      // height of button

  // constructor
  Button(String labelB, float xpos, float ypos, float widthB, float heightB) {
    label = labelB;
    x = xpos;
    y = ypos;
    w = widthB;
    h = heightB;
  }

  void Draw() {
    fill(218);
    stroke(141);
    rect(x, y, w, h, 10);
    textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
    fill(0);
    text(label, x + (w / 2), y + (h / 2));
  }

  boolean MouseIsOver() {
    if (mouseX > x && mouseX < (x + w) && mouseY > y && mouseY < (y + h)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

which is running in a Processing sketch. In the sketch, the action of mouse is pressed on the specific button is defined by `MouseIsOver`. I want my HTML page to know my button is clicked and do the following action. Any useful suggestion will be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

JSP runs on a server. You need this code to run on the client, in the browser itself.

To do that, you either need to use [Processing.js](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/processing-js) to deploy your Processing sketch as JavaScript, then you can use [this guide](http://processingjs.org/articles/PomaxGuide.html) to write code that interacts between pure JavaScript and your Processing.js.

Or you could port your sketch to [P5.js](https://p5js.org/), which you've already tagged your question with. This would involve rewriting all of your Processing code from scratch in P5.js, which is JavaScript.

I'm a little confused about why clicking a button creates a file though. That file should probably already be there instead of you creating it manually when the sketch is run.

Comment: Thank you Kevin! So for creating files, I used "new skecth" button. Every time I clicked, it will automatically create files with ".html" and ".js" extension in the sketch folder.